How can I list the files that are in one S3 bucket but not in the other bucket?
I have two AWS S3 buckets that have mostly the same content but with a few differences. How can I list the files that are in one bucket but not in the other bucket?

Just install the AWS CLI, then set it up as Amazon Web Services specifies here, then type:
aws s3 ls --recursive s3://BucketN1 > listbucket1.txt

aws s3 ls --recursive s3://BucketN2 > listbucket2.txt

diff -u listbucket1.txt listbucket2.txt| grep '^-[^-]' | sed 's/^-//'

Ensure the first list contains the files you want to show, otherwise flip the order of the two lists.
Relevant addendum: if you're on Windows you can install cygwin or wsl in order to have diff available.

S3 Inventory can also be used to do something similar and will probably be more efficient if there are a large number of objects. Also does not require the use of the CLI
